Content versioning and its impact on record fluctuation
How are others doing content versioning regarding technical documentation and search with Algolia?
Are they only including the latest content version, or including other previous versions? That is what drives this number so understanding recommended practices would help.
(Summarized a customer question who doesn't have a consistent number of records and is trying to understand how to project his needs?_
I looked at the usage in the admin dash and saw that there's a lot of fluctuation in the records which isn't typical. When I asked the customer to help estimate their needs, they couldnt and asked my question
